# Extracting first PDF page as graphic on Windows without Ghostscript

Tags: python, windows, pdf

I am looking for a solution to extract the first page of PDF files
on Windows as an image without having to install Ghostscript (too ´huge dependency).
I tried ImageMagick (convert) but this delegates also to Ghostscript.
Are there some other self-contained tools for performing this task on Windows?

For the integration I am looking for a solution that is either directly
available on the Python level or through an os.system() call or similar.

Comment: `ghostscript` is like the very basic requirement for processing of PDFs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest [Poppler](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/) or [MuPDF](http://www.mupdf.com/). Later provides binary for Windows and from my experience (on Linux though) is very efficient. Poppler is licensed GPLv2, MuPDF is GPLv3.

Update: Unfortunately MuPDF switched to Affero GPLv3 since version 1.2.